# Office365 smtp not always working with php mailer

Tags: php, smtp, office365, phpmailer

I'm trying to use office365 smtp with phpmailer, it authenticates and it delivers sometime but sometimes it does. Not in inbox or spam. It works well with other smtp server. Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;  
$mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = $host;
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = $user;                 
$mail->Password = $pass;                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "STARTTLS";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = $port;                                   

$mail->From = $from_email;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;

foreach($recipients as $recipients){
$mail->AddBcc($recipients);
}

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($message);
```

Comment: So what errors are you seeing? How exactly does it fail? We have nothing to go on here. Your `SMTPSecure` value is wrong, see the docs and examples for valid options.

Comment: No error, it's shows message sent successfully, sometimes it delivers sometimes it doesn't. I've tried tls as the SMTPSecure value as well. Same issue

Comment: If it sends ok but doesn't arrive, then it's not your sending script that's the problem. Check your mail server logs, set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and post the transcript for a message (that doesn't get delivered) in your question. We still don't have enough information to go on here.

Comment: It's working now thank you. I left it alone for a while, it worked when I tested, I also removed the x-mailer value which original has GitHub and phpmailer as default.